# How can I select all options of a multiple amp-selector?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have an `amp-selector` with `multiple` options. I know that if I want to clear all the selections, I can bind `<apm-selector-id>.clear` on a `tap` event on a button.

Example:

```
<button on="tap:mySelector.clear">Clear Selection</button>
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in order to select all options? I have many options and I do not want to compel my user to click on each one of them, if they want to select them all. I just want them to click on a button and have all options selected, all together, with one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no action registered that does what you are asking.

[amp-selector source](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/bcfcb2e12ec11bac2e7ed403498ae5ae5e4bd92d/extensions/amp-selector/0.1/amp-selector.js)

However, you can fork the repo on github, add the functionality and do a pull request. It's pretty simple and easy to do.

Another option you have is to start out with all options selected and have the user deselect the undesired ones.